# Internet connectivity: ping OK, tracert OK, MSN OK, but neither IE/FF nor Skype work

Tags: windows, internet-connection

From day to day, a friend has a problem with his internet connectivity.

I suggested him to test `ipconfig /all`, `ping` and `tracert`, and they return regular response.

No proxy is configured, and MSN can connect.

He also uninstalled his out-of-date antivirus.

Do you have some ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: need more details on the problem: Do specific applications not connect (has any browser worked)? or, are specific sites unreachable? Are unreachable things always unreachable? Or, is there intermittent connectivity? Has this internet connection been tried with a different PC or a different OS on this PC (like Ubuntu LiveCD) -- what were the results?

Comment: No site or FTP are reachable. He doesn't have any LiveCD. I just suggested him to run Lynx for Win32. I'm waiting for the result.

Comment: msn can connect but there is no connectivity? he sees contacts and it signs in?

Comment: I know it's strange about MSN. I'll try to get more details.

Comment: On MSN he can sign in and see his contacts. And Lynx says: `Unable to connect to remote host.`